# No sound (Everest ESSX8336 sound card)

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I bought the huawei D16 to me and my wife. Her notebook has a realteck sound card inside and installing the ubuntu has no problem. But my version of this has Everest ESSX8336 inside. And when I sign in Ubuntu I haven't sound any where.

Linux github repo has [changes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/sound/soc/codecs/es8316.c) for sound card.
So, I have installed the latest ubuntu === 21.10 and update the kernel to 5.16-rc1.
But it doesn't help to me.

I got only dummy output inside settings.

Screens from windows 10 where all is working correctly.

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

[image: Screenshot 2]

---

[image: Screenshot 3]

---

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: It looks like the support changes have been commited to the 5.16 kernel. Current kernel for 21.10 is only 5.13, so you will need to wait a while.