# Internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, amd-processor, huawei

Internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04. Only Dummy output in the selection of output device.

UPDATE (2021-12-04) - I made a conclusion after reading posts of owners of Huawei Matebook D16 that the problem is with sound card (Everest) in this model of laptop. It's not supported yet.

Detailed alsa information: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0728a726fdfae280fcc1b9fc801432288a931cf3

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

There are only HDMI in the list of Playback hardware devices, may be problem is here? Notebook is Huawei Matebood 16D with AMD core.

I tried a lot of solutions found on the internet:

1. Add lines to "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

2. Add "radeon.audio=1" to "/etc/default/grub"

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

3. Remove and reinstall "analog"

```
sudo apt-get remove analog
sudo apt-get install analog
```

4. Update linux Kernel to 5.15.6

Nothing helped to hear sound on Ubuntu :( Audio works on Windows.

Comment: *There are only HDMI in the list of Playback hardware devices, may be problem is here?* Yes. Internal speakers are connected to the internal sound card that isn't being detected. HDMI audio comes from the sound chip/layer in the GPU.

Comment: thank you for answer. Is it possible to detect card ? i found <https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS> but there are no package for ubuntu 20.04 on amd64..

Comment: Comments aren't answers. The intent was to confirm your suspicion and focus the troubleshooting. I don't know enough to help you with this but others hopefully can.

Comment: I have similar problem with Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 6.5. Have you succeeded to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your ALSA have loaded snd_acp3x_rn module, but card was not recognized fully, unlike snd_hda_intel. Since you are using dual boot, **the problem can be ‘Fast Startup’**, that puts hardware into a hybrid hibernation state instead of a full shutdown. Disabling Fast Startup is a must when dual-booting. Shutdown.

The origin of this hint is here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-from-speakers-no-sound-from-3-5mm-jack-audio-amd-thinkpad-e595/13717/6

EDIT: another idea. There can be wrong module loaded for your sound card. Try to blacklist the following modules in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
    blacklist snd_acp3x_rn
    blacklist snd-acp3x-pdm-dma
    blacklist snd-acpx-rn
    blacklist snd-rn-pci-acp3x
```

Blacklist them one-by-one, reboot after each. Check the result with `aplay -l`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I disabled Fast Boot in Windows. There is not FastBoot settings in bios in huawei matebook d16. It disn't help. Apperently, it's a problem of new sound card in this laptop.

Comment: @Fedortaf if it is Everest card, then, accordingly to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375830/no-sound-everest-essx8336-sound-card) it is not supported yet by current kernel of Ubuntu 20.04.